# asp.net wiki user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, wiki, web-controls

I'm writing a asp.net web application in which I want the users to be able to apply simple formatting to the text they enter in text areas.

One of the possibilities is to use a javascript wisywig editor (like tinymce). However, to keep the text html-clean and readible, I'd prefer that the users have to do the formatting themselves in exactly the same way as it is done in wiki's.

I can't find a free or not too expensive control on the web. Has anyone used a third party control before? any advise on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a markdown editor like this:

http://wmd-editor.com/

Then you want to be able display the result in HTML with this:

http://aspnetresources.com/blog/markdown_announced.aspx

Essentially this is what [StackOverflow](http://Stackoverflow.com) does (with their customization). They discuss how they do it in [their podcast](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W12621).